# how to force ansible to use http + kerberos (error WINRM CONNECTION ERROR: 401 Unauthorized.)

Tags: ansible, winrm

I am configuring ansible (CentOS 6.7) to connnect to windows machine using http, winRM and kerberos

From the `/etc/ansible/host` file

```
[training]
machinename:5985
```

I have set host specific yaml file

```
ansible_winrm_scheme: http
ansible_port: 5985
ansible_connection: winrm
```

Then, following command

```
 ansible machinename -m win_ping -vvvv
```

errors with following

```
<machinename > ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: jnambood on PORT 5985 TO machinename 
<machinename > WINRM CONNECT: transport=plaintext endpoint=http://machinename :5985/wsman
<machinename > WINRM CONNECTION ERROR: 401 Unauthorized.


<machinename > WINRM CONNECT: transport=plaintext endpoint=https://machinename :5985/wsman
<machinename > WINRM CONNECTION ERROR: 500 WinRMTransport. [Errno 1] _ssl.c:492: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
machinename  | FAILED => 500 WinRMTransport. [Errno 1] _ssl.c:492: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

Ansible tried to http, got 401 error. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you have installed the kerberos module and ansible_user contains @
>   (e.g. username@realm), Ansible will first attempt Kerberos
>   authentication. This method uses the principal you are authenticated
>   to Kerberos with on the control machine and not `ansible_user`. If
>   that fails, either because you are not signed into Kerberos on the
>   control machine or because the corresponding domain account on the
>   remote host is not available, then Ansible will fall back to “plain”
>   username/password authentication. [~Ansible Windows Introduction](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html#inventory)

```
$ cat ansible/group_vars/os-windows.yml
# <user>@<realm> means use principal in krb5cc, name here doesn't matter
ansible_ssh_user: use@KERBEROS
ansible_ssh_port: 5985
ansible_connection: winrm

$ ansible host.ad.example.com -m win_ping -o
host.ad.example.com | success >> {"changed": false, "ping": "pong"}
```